# Change line in regex python

Tags: python, regex

I have a few lines of string e.g:

```
AR0003242303
TR0402304004
CR0402340404
```

I want to create a dictionary from these lines.

And I need to create change it in regex to:

```
KOLAORM0003242303
KOLTORM0402304004
KOLCORM0402340404
```

So i need to split first 2 characters, before PUT `KOL`, between PUT `O`, and Afer second char put `M`. How can i reach it. Through many attempts I lose patience with the regex and unfortunately I now I have no time to learn it better now. Need some result now :(

Could someone help me with this case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `re.sub` --> `re.sub(r"^([A-Z])([A-Z])", r"KOL\1O\2M", string)`

**Ex:**

```
import re

s = ["AR0003242303", "TR0402304004", "CR0402340404"]
for i in s:
    print( re.sub(r"^([A-Z])([A-Z])", r"KOL\1O\2M", i) )
```

**Output:**

```
KOLAORM0003242303
KOLTORM0402304004
KOLCORM0402340404
```

Comment: Thank u very much for help. For better understand: ([A-Z])([A-Z]) means only A-Z characters... KOL is that what i need to put in first step, but how works \10\2M ?

Comment: `\1` & `\2` are the groups in the regex. --> `([A-Z])([A-Z])`

Answer (score 2):

You don't need regex for this, you can do it with getting the list of characters from the string, recreate the list, and join the string back

```
def get_convert_s(s):
    li = list(s)
    li = ['KOL', li[0], '0', li[1], 'M', *li[2:]]
    return ''.join(li)

print(get_convert_s('AR0003242303'))
#KOLA0RM0003242303
print(get_convert_s('TR0402304004'))
#KOLT0RM0402304004
print(get_convert_s('CR0402340404'))
#KOLC0RM0402340404
```

Answer (score 2):

```py
import re

regex = re.compile(r"([A-Z])([A-Z])([0-9]+)")

inputs = [
    'AR0003242303',
    'TR0402304004',
    'CR0402340404'
]

results = []
for input in inputs:
    matches = re.match(regex, input)
    groups = matches.groups()
    results.append('KOL{}O{}M{}'.format(*groups))

print(results)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the length of the strings in your list will always be the same Devesh answers is pretty much the best approach (no reason to overcomplicate it).

My solution is similar to Devesh, I just like writing functions as oneliners:

```
list = ["AR0003242303", "TR0402304004", "CR0402340404"]

def convert_s(s):
    return "KOL"+s[0]+"0"+s[1]+"M"+s[2:]

for str in list:
   print(convert_s(str));
```

Altough it returns the same output.